# Running Qt 5.3 application on /dev/fb1

Tags: qt, arm, embedded-linux, framebuffer

I want to run Qt application on fb1 of an ARM board. I'm trying to run

```
`./QTExample -platform directfb`
```

from minicom but I get no output window, but the following log:

```
(*) DirectFB/Core: Single Application Core. (2014-09-08 11:26) 
(*) Direct/Memcpy: Using armasm_memcpy()
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Fusion Dispatch' (-1) [MESSAGING OTHER/OTHER 0/0] <8388608>...
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'VT Switcher' (-1) [CRITICAL OTHER/OTHER 0/0] <8388608>...
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'VT Flusher' (-1) [DEFAULT OTHER/OTHER 0/0] <8388608>...
(*) DirectFB/FBDev: Found 'tegra_fb' (ID 0) with frame buffer at 0xf7c00000, 18432k (MMIO 0x00000000, 0k)
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Linux Input' (-1) [INPUT OTHER/OTHER 0/0] <8388608>...
(*) DirectFB/Input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse (1) 0.1 (directfb.org)
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Linux Input' (-1) [INPUT OTHER/OTHER 0/0] <8388608>...
(*) DirectFB/Input: CHICONY HP Basic USB Keyboard (2) 0.1 (directfb.org)
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Hotplug with Linux Input' (-1) [INPUT OTHER/OTHER 0/0] <8388608>...
(*) DirectFB/Input: Hot-plug detection enabled with Linux Input Driver 
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Keyboard Input' (-1) [INPUT OTHER/OTHER 0/0] <8388608>...
(*) DirectFB/Input: Keyboard 0.9 (directfb.org)
(*) DirectFB/Graphics: Generic Software Rasterizer 0.7 (directfb.org)
(*) DirectFB/Core/WM: Default 0.3 (directfb.org)
(*) FBDev/Mode: Setting 640x480 RGB32
(*) FBDev/Mode: Switched to 640x480 (virtual 640x960) at 32 bit (RGB32), pitch 2560
(*) FBDev/Mode: Setting 640x480 RGB32
(*) FBDev/Mode: Switched to 640x480 (virtual 640x960) at 32 bit (RGB32), pitch 2560
 (!!!)  *** UNIMPLEMENTED [fusion_get_fusionee_pid] *** [fusion.c:3517]
```

My idea is that it is trying to run on /dev/fb0 which is not what I want. My question is, how can I instruct to run the application on **/dev/fb1**

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/embedded-linux.html) you should be able to specify `-platform linuxfb:fb=/dev/fb1` and it should work, although I'm not quite sure how `linuxfb` differs from `directfb` (`linuxfb` and `directfb` seem to be both mentioned as Qt plugins but the names are used interchangeably in many places), but you could still try this out.

**EDIT**

I looked around a little more since I also work a lot with QT/embedded devices in my free time
and this looked interesting. Qt source code didn't state the device id explicitly anywhere (at least as far as I looked) in the `directfb` plugin code, but according to [this](http://directfb.org/wiki/index.php/Configuring_DirectFB) wiki page in `directfb.org` you can actually provide the configuration for directfb in a file. So basically you could try and make a file `~/.directfbrc` with one line `devfb=/dev/fb1`. Hope this works.

Comment: directfb is an open source library while linuxfb allows the QT app to write directly to the frame buffer

Comment: I have tried all combinations of -platform argument without any success

Comment: @Hamzahfrq can you check if the DirectFB configuration file works as mentioned in the edit?

Comment: I think you mean `devfb`, because busid is something else. I have already tried ~/.directfb as well but I get a black screen - I think my problem lies in controlling frame buffer directly. I am not able to see something on display even if I try to write something on the FB directly.

Comment: +1 for your help (and probably correct solution). I will accept the answer when I am able to see a result on the FB